# I Need to get to 500 simultaneous connections which needs to build by say 100 every 5 minutes. after that redecue at the samerate

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I Need to get to 500 simultaneous connections which  needs to build by say 100 every 5 minutes. after that redecue at the samerate, using Jmeter script.

Answer (score 1):

From my very limited understanding of your question it appears you're looking for [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/), the relevant configuration would be something like:

[image]

You can install Ultimate Thread Group as a part of [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

Comment: how can i reduce at the same rate?